# Asking the user if they want to play again - code repeats anyway when I type "n"

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
play = True

while play:
    #1 A company gives bonus of 5% to employees with year of service of more than 5 years.
    salary = float(input("Insert your salary "))
    bonus = float((salary * 0.05) + salary)
    yearOfService = int(input("Insert how many years you have worked "))

    if yearOfService > 5:
        print ("You now have $" + str(round(bonus,2)))
    else:
        print ("Sorry, but you need to have more than 5 years of service for a bonus.")

    #2 A school's grading system.
    score = float(input("Enter your score: "))
    print("Your score is " + str(score))
    grade = ""
    if score < 25:
        grade = "F"
    if score >= 25 and score <= 45:
        grade = "E"
    if score >= 45 and score <=50:
        grade = "D"
    if score >= 50 and score <= 60:
        grade = "C"
    if score >= 60 and score <= 80:
        grade = "B"
    if score > 80:
        grade = "A"
    print("Your grade is " + grade)

    #3 Weird/Not Weird
    for i in range(0,3):
        n = float(input("Enter integer: "))
        if n%2 == 1:
            print "Weird"
        if n%2 == 0 and n <= 2 and n >= 5:
            print "Not Weird"
        if n%2 == 0 and n <= 6 and n >= 20:
            print "Weird"
        if n%2 == 0 and n > 20:
            print "Not Weird"

    #4. In a given string "mississippi" count number of 's' and 'i'
    string = "mississippi"
    sCount = 0
    iCount = 0

    for i in string:
        if i == 's':
            sCount = sCount + 1
        if i == 'i':
            iCount = iCount + 1
    print( str(sCount) + " s's and " + str(iCount) + "i's")

    #5. Print "Hello World" 8 times
    f = 1
    while f <= 8:
        print("Hello World")
        f += 1

    again = input("Would you like to play again?")
    if again == "n":
        play = False
```

However when I tested my code, everything looked good except when I typed "n" at the end, it just repeated anyways, even though I put "if again == "n": play = False" at the end, making it act useless in the code. How do I make the code stop when I type "n"? Thanks!

Comment: are you typing n or "n" for exiting the game?

Comment: Your problem is merely with the loop repetition; why is all of the other code here?
Also, do *not* expect us to supply the input: you do that with a hard-coded variable.

Comment: Typing n and hitting enter exited the game for me.

Comment: @user2263572 same here

Comment: Try to output your values, like `print("again: %s." % again)`, also this `if again == "n": play = False` can be replaced by `play = again != 'n'`

Comment: As an aside, counting the number of instances of a character in a string is built-in: `'mississippi'.count('i')` correctly evaluates to `4`. Also, don't use `round` to show a floating-point value to a specific number of decimal places, because [floating-point numbers don't work that way](https://floating-point-gui.de/); instead, use string formatting.

Comment: Other issues aside, why are you seemingly mixing Python 2 and 3 syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Oh, this is a fun one.

First we need to look at line 36:

```
print "Weird"
```

Because *this did not cause an error*, it means the code is running under Python 2.x. (It's clear from the rest of your code that you intend to use a 3.x version of Python, where this would have caused a syntax error.)

In 2.x, `input` interprets the input text as a Python expression in the current context; it's equivalent to making a call to `eval()` on the input text. (You do not want to do this.)

What happens is that because you have a *variable* `n` earlier in the program, the text `n` that you typed in evaluates to that variable's value (i.e., the weird or not-weird number from before). (If you had instead typed `y` for example, an exception would have been raised.)

Solution: You need to fix your `print` function calls, and then ensure that you use a Python 3.x interpreter for the code.

Comment: Ah, ha!  *That* would be why I got the `float` error just now while trying to diagnose this.

Comment: Or if you are using Python 2.x for some reason, `raw_input` is the function you want to use.

Comment: Because Python 2.x is [no longer being maintained](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/), I am working under the assumption that no *new* programmers have a legitimate reason to be using it.

Comment: I was working on a Python 2.x program and I tried it out on a Python 3 program to correct the print function calls and it worked, thanks!